# Living in a city with multiple minhagim hamakom, but none of them is his minhag avot

Tags: minhagim

We assume that a Jew has a minhag avot, but he lives in a city where there are several synagogues (each following a different minhag), none of which follow his minhag avot. What should he do?

Comment: Minhag avot in private, minhag hamakom in public

Comment: @mbloch or join a community permanently (as the OP has been told multiple times)

Comment: @mbloch One more detail: minhag hamakom only if it is shaliach tzibur. If you are a non-leader, you should wear a tallit, wear tefillin, and say the silent Amidah according to the minhag avot, and say the prayers out loud in the minhag hamakom. Anyway thank you.

Comment: Once again: Rabbi Feinstein gave someone the option to do the silent prayers according to their personal minhag, OR the communal one, with a slight preference towards the latter. (THERE ARE MULTIPLE CORRECT ANSWERS HERE!!!!) If it's Chol HaMoed and the community does *not* wear tefillin, you should not do so in their presence. Most communities today don't care if someone single is wearing a Tallit, but if they had a communal custom *against* it, then do not!

Comment: Similarly, a single man of East European ancestry entering a German-Jewish synagogue will probably be told -- *you are going to wear a tallit here*, like it or not. And anyone who gets an aliyah Shabbos mincha at a German synagogue is expected to keep the tallit on for all of mincha. And Rabbi Hershel Schachter objected to someone wearing a colored-fabric tallit at Yeshiva University -- "not our yeshiva's minhag." As a tallit gadol is quite visible, minhag hamakom absolutely could dictate what someone wears or doesn't.

Comment: It just happens to be that in the most typical case -- most single men aren't wearing one, but this single man would like to -- in the typical synagogue today, minhag hamakom happens to be to shrug.

Comment: Minhag hamakom only if it is shaliach tzibur. If you are a non-leader, you should wear a tallit, wear tefillin, and say the silent Amidah according to the minhag avot, and say the prayers out loud in the minhag hamakom. Sources: https://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Tefillin_on_Chol_HaMoed#:~:text=Later%2C%20in%20hilchos%20Chol%20HaMoed,may%20nevertheless%20write%20the%20Tefillin.